# Pandas split a cell value to lots with '\n' but keep them in the same row

Tags: pandas, split, row

I have a demo code here to describe the requirement:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['Item1','Item2','Item3'],'Des':['Welcome\nto use Python','Hello','Python\nis\ngood']})
print(df)
```

output:

```
    Item                     Des
0  Item1  Welcome\nto use Python
1  Item2                   Hello
2  Item3        Python\nis\ngood
```

You can see below that `Welcome\nto use Python` is split into 2 phases(words) with`\n`, but `Welcome` and `to use Python` are still in the same row.

```
    Item                     Des
0  Item1                   Welcome
                           to use Python
1  Item2                   Hello
2  Item3                   Python
                           is
                           good
```

That's the requirement. I can split the cell value to a list but have no idea about the next steps. Could you please give some suggestions on how to implement it with Pandas? Thanks.

```
df['Des_'] = df['Des'].apply(lambda x: x.split('\n'))
```

When I save it to excel, it should be like:

[image: save to excel]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
df.assign(Des=df['Des'].str.split('\n')).explode('Des')
```

Output:

```
    Item            Des
0  Item1        Welcome
0  Item1  to use Python
1  Item2          Hello
2  Item3         Python
2  Item3             is
2  Item3           good
```

Comment: Thanks, but it may need further steps to deal with the dataFrame.Because the final purpose is to save the dataFrame to excel which only 3 rows like just the picture in the question description. Warp text into the same row where there is a `\n`.